# Getting two values from same Joined table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have two tables:

- procedures
- countries

Table **procedures** has two columns

1. destination_country_iso
2. origin_country_iso

Table **countries**

1. iso
2. name

Im trying to join up the two tables in order to get both destination an origin country name from countries table.

```
SELECT *
FROM draft_procedures AS drp
LEFT JOIN countries AS c1 ON drp.destination_country_iso = c1.iso
LEFT JOIN countries AS c2 ON drp.origin_country_iso = c2.iso
```

The SQL result display proper result, but I now have two duplicate columns "name" and Im unable to retrieve them with the php code:

```
$destination_country=$row['c1.name'];
```

Comment: Use $row['column name or allias'].

Comment: Don't use "SELECT *". Name, and the alias, the columns you want returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

access it like this

```
SELECT drp.*,c1.name as c1name,c2.name as c2name
then
$row['c1name'] $row['c2name']
```